# Symfony2.2 @Assert\Image not working

Tags: validation, symfony

Completely misses any files.

If I use Assert \ File works, but then does not take minWidth, minHeight

Purpose: 
1) The file must be an image. 
2) Make a limit on the resolution of the image

My Entity:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Image(
 *     minWidth = 150,
 *     maxWidth = 150,
 *     minHeight = 190,
 *     maxHeight = 190
 * )
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Додайте будь ласка фотографію")
 */
protected $file;

   /**
 * Sets file.
 *
 * @param UploadedFile $file
 */
public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
{
    $this->file = $file;
}

/**
 * Get file.
 *
 * @return UploadedFile
 */
public function getFile()
{
    return $this->file;
}
```

Generate form:

```
$builder
        ->add('file', 'file', array(
            'label' => 'Ваша фотографія (Обов`язковий розмір: 150*190)',
            'required' => true,))
```

Comment: The problem was solved. The problem was that only certain validation applied grupy.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem. How did you solve this issue?